# Google ads and/or DoubleClick wants to access the keyboard API in Firefox?

Tags: access-control, google

I have started Firefox in an Ubuntu terminal, and now I see these messages during browsing:

"No permission to use the keyboard API for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net"

I mean... WTF? Why does Google Ads or DoubleClick need to have access to my keyboard?

Comment: Time to install [AdBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) and [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/)...

Comment: I am aware of those, but I cannot install these in certain corporate environments... And let me also mention that these add-ons are not under Mozilla's strict release management.

Comment: Looks quite interesting to me. Here's someone who had a similar output: http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/GoogleAds-API-usage-td4095582.html